# Why does my SSIS package run in Visual Studio but fails validation on the server?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS Package that reads from two tables (on different instances), performs a Merge Join and the uses a Conditional Split to update one of the source tables. I have a single connection manger set up and use an linked server to access one of the tables on another instance. In the connection manager I use a login and a saved password with permissions to the databases and tables. It runs like a champ in Visual Studio. When I deploy it to my SQL Server 2016, it fails validation with the error "Update Customers:Error: Customer Data failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801B."

I have tried to move the linked server to it's own connection manager with a saved password. I also tried using Windows Authentication in the connection manager. These didn't work either. Also, when I search for the error code 0xC020801B nothing seems to come up.

EDIT:

The Package ProtectionLevel is EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey.

EDIT II:

I changed the connection manager from a Project connection manager to a Package connection manager. I now get the error:

Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" HResult: 0x80040E4D Description: "Login failed for user 'integration'."

The user integration has access to the databases and the tables in question. I also tried to remove the login and use Windows Authentication. I added the server as a login with db_datareader and db_datawriter permissions on both databases. When I deploy and execute the package I get the error on the linked server connection:

Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" HResult: 0x80040E4D Description: "Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\INSTANCE_NAME$'."

Comment: Could you post what is your Package Protection Level https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2091/securing-your-ssis-packages-using-package-protection-level/

Comment: @Piotr I added it as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ProtectionLevel "EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey", which means that all sensitive data including passwords are encrypted using windows encryption based on your login.
When you deploy the package to the server, it is not able to decrypt these passwords.
Please use "DontSaveSensitive" and provide all passwords using package parameters.

Or better option is to use windows authentication and grant required privileges to your service account.

Comment: If you want to deploy EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey then the package will need to be built under whatever account on the SQL Server that is used to execute the package.

Answer (score -1):

I found this ...

https://imgalib.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/how-to-solve-ssis-error-code-0xc020801c0xc004700c0xc0047017/

It could be worth checking for drivers etc on the server